# Search and extract value using JQ command line processor

Tags: json, jq, lookup

I have a JSON file very similar to the following:

```
[
  {
    "uuid": "832390ed-58ed-4338-bf97-eb42f123d9f3",
    "name": "Nacho"
  },
  {
    "uuid": "5b55ea5e-96f4-48d3-a258-75e152d8236a",
    "name": "Taco"
  },
  {
    "uuid": "a68f5249-828c-4265-9317-fc902b0d65b9",
    "name": "Burrito"
  }
]
```

I am trying to figure out how to use the JQ command line processor to first find the UUID that I input and based on that output the name of the associated item. So for example, if I input UUID a68f5249-828c-4265-9317-fc902b0d65b9 it should search the JSON file, find the matching UUID and then return the name Burrito. I am doing this in Bash. I realize it may require some outside logic in addition to JQ. I will keep thinking about it and put an update here in a bit. I know I could do it in an overly complicated way, but I know there is probably a really simple JQ method of doing this in one or two lines. Please help me.

https://shapeshed.com/jq-json/#how-to-find-a-key-and-value

Comment: why is this marked as too broad ?

Comment: @Atomiklan - What if there is more than one occurrence of the specified `uuid` value?

Comment: @ Atomiklan, there's also an _alternative_ solution for the JSON manipulation in your questions - based on a new `walk-path` unix utility jtc: **`uuid='a68f5249-828c-4265-9317-fc902b0d65b9'; <file.json jtc -w"<$uuid>[-1][name]"`**. The `walk-path` there is rather trivial, but I can elaborate in a separate answer if you like (PS. I'm a developer of the tool).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use select:

```
jq -r  --arg query Burrito '.[] | select( .name == $query ) | .uuid ' tst.json
```

Comment: Any idea how to get a variable into Burrito though?

Comment: Seems single quotes works '$variable' but JQ freaks out with a compile error.

Comment: jq -r '.[] | select( .uuid == '$test') | .name '

Comment: Based on what had been asked, it should be the other way around, `jq -r --arg query a68f5249-828c-4265-9317-fc902b0d65b9 '.[] | select( .uuid == $query ) | .name ' tst.json`

Comment: Yes you are correct. I just flipped around Sorin's answer.